# How to get Android Market licensing sample to work?

Tags: android

I downloaded the sdk and added the library to my workspace, then the sample for market licensing.  The sample app seems to force close somewhere after/during the instantiation of LicenseChecker.  I tried running on the emulator with Google API 8 and on a droid x with froyo and it force closes.  The stack shows PerformLaunchActivity as the top item.
Both emulator and phone had a registered gmail account.

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, simple answer was look in the code and replace the public key as it says.

Comment: You can get it to work, but you [can't test it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365118/market-licensing-example-always-getting-licensed). Currently, there is no way to test it, unless you publish it. Catch 22.