# Market Licensing Example always getting LICENSED

Tags: android, google-play, android-lvl

Despite changing the `License Test Response` to `NOT_LICENSED` in the Publisher's [Edit Profile](http://market.android.com/publish/editProfile) page, I am still receiving in the "Market Licensing Example" a `LICENSED` response.

I didn't modify the "[Market Licensing Example](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#dev-setup)" in any way (except for the mandatory BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY and changing `com.example` to 'com.somethingelse' of course).

What am I missing and how do I get the response I set in my Publisher's account for testing purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering myself:

In the [Server Response Codes](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#server-response-codes) table, it says:

> LICENSED: The application is licensed to the user. The user has
>   purchased the application **or the
>   application only exists as a draft**.

OK, so the question now is: How, on earth, am I supposed to learn what I need to learn from the "Market Licensing Example" if it *always returns LICENSED and I cannot really upload it other than draft???*

This is [catch 22!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497280/android-not-market-managed-error/3532788#3532788)

Answer (score 0):

I can change and get a reliable response IF I use a device with the developer account as its main account (good thing I have a couple of devices lying around...) or if the account has been added as test accounts (wouldnt work all the time).

Otherwise it will always say licensed with a VT/GT? attached as an Extra with a max long as value.