# Google play lvl always return LICENSED

Tags: android, android-lvl

I know that this question was asked several times, but i've tried a lot to resolve my problem without success.

My use case is :

- i've uploaded an apk on google play (as draft but activated)
- i've this same apk on my phone
- i've signed in on my phone with my publisher account
- i've set up the NOT_LICENSED response in my console google play.

But i always get the LICENSED Code response.

Any idea where i may be wrong?

Thanks for the help

Comment: On your device, try Settings -> Applications -> Google Play Store -> Clear cache/data.

Comment: Already tried, nothing change.

Comment: @tdurand do you know any solution for this me also facing the same issue here is my question link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169622/android-licensing-application-not-works

Comment: No, i didn't try again, i've release my app without licencing

Answer (score 1):

In the [Server Response Codes table](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/licensing/licensing-reference.html) of the Android Developers documentation you'll find the following decription of the LICENSED response:

> The application is licensed to the user. The user has purchased the application or **the application only exists as a draft**. [emphasis mine]

So it looks like the reason you're getting that code is listed in your first bullet point: your apk only exists as a draft.

You can also refer to [this other similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365118/market-licensing-example-always-getting-licensed).